# pandas read_csv convert object to float

Tags: pandas

i'm trying to read a csv file. in one column (hpi) which should be float32 there are two records populated with a . to indicate missing values. pandas interprets the . as a character.

how do force numeric on this column?

```
data = pd.read_csv('http://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_state.csv',
                    header=0,
                    names = ["state", "year", "qtr", "hpi"])

                    #,converters={'hpi': float})

#print data.head()
#print(data.dtypes)

print(data[data.hpi == '.'])
```

Comment: please write your code in a readable way (surround the entire code piece with apostrophes). You can edit the original message to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Would it be Ok it you'd have any numeric value instead of '.'? (_e.g._ -1, 999, etc.)

Comment: yes, but the field has decimal places. 
0    AK  1975    2  63.40
1    AK  1975    3  66.60
2    AK  1975    4  67.91
3    AK  1976    1  70.45
4    AK  1976    2  71.83


     state  year  qtr hpi
7593    VT  1976    1   .
8112    WV  1982    1   .


>>>

Comment: decimal places don't matter if you manually edit the type (see my answer below). any int (_e.g._ -1) will turn to float (-1.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `na.values` parameter in [read.csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_state.csv',
                  header=0,
                  names = ["state", "year", "qtr", "hpi"], 
                  na_values='.')

df.dtypes
Out: 
state     object
year       int64
qtr        int64
hpi      float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply [to_numeric](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) over the desired column (with [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)):

```
data.loc[data.hpi == '.', 'hpi'] = -1.0
data[['hpi']] = data[['hpi']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

For example:

```
In[69]: data = pd.read_csv('http://www.fhfa.gov/DataTools/Downloads/Documents/HPI/HPI_AT_state.csv',
                    header=0,
                    names = ["state", "year", "qtr", "hpi"])

In[70]: data[['hpi']].dtypes
  Out[70]: 
  hpi    object
  dtype: object

In[74]: data.loc[data.hpi == '.'] = -1.0
In[75]: data[['hpi']] = data[['hpi']].apply(pd.to_numeric)

In[77]: data[['hpi']].dtypes
Out[77]: 
hpi    float64
dtype: object
```

**EDIT:**

For some reason it changes all the columns to `float64`. This is a small workaround that changes them back to `int`.

Before:

```
In[89]: data.dtypes
Out[89]: 
state     object
year     float64
qtr      float64
hpi      float64
```

After:

```
In[90]: data[['year','qtr']] = data[['year','qtr']].astype(int)
In[91]: data.dtypes
Out[91]: 
state     object
year       int64
qtr        int64
hpi      float64
dtype: object
```

If anyone could shed light over way it happens that'd be great.

Comment: thanks, appreciate the help. but it changed the datatype on all numeric columns to float64. is there a way to isolate it to just the hpi column?

Comment: You're right, It's pretty strange. Couldn't solve it elegantly, but I added (under **EDIT**) a workaround.

Comment: BTW you could use `astype(float)` instead of `apply(pd.to_numeric)`.

Comment: `data.loc[data.hpi == '.'] = -1.0` means set all columns to -1 when you see this condition. You need to change it to `data.loc[data.hpi == '.', 'hpi'] = -1.0`

Comment: This was the solution for me. My column was entirely numeric by spreadsheet assessment, but registered as object in pandas for unknow reasons (whitespace?). Calling `df.somecol = pd.to_numeric(df.somecol)` resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could just cast this after you read it in. e.g.

```
data.loc[data.hpi == '.', 'hpi'] = pd.np.nan
data.hpi = data.hpi.astype(pd.np.float64)
```

Alternatively you can use the `na_values` parameter for `read_csv`

Comment: is this the only way to do it? no way to do it when it reads it in correct?

Comment: No you can also use `read_csv` which is likely the best way in this scenario. Depending on how much post processing you are doing after reading the data though / if you don't want to read through the docstrings to remember the key/pair name I sometimes find the above easier.